# How to put several gauge charts of different limit in a html page?

Tags: limit, gauge

How could I display more than 1 gauge chart in a html page. But each limit of gauge chart is different.
Example
(Max value)  New York  max  is 1000,  Boston max is 1200,  Miami max is 1333
(Red region)  New York redFrom is 0, redTo is 450,
Boston  redFrom is 0, redTo is 600,
Miami   redFrom is 0, redTo is 500

How could I modify this code or some useful method?

```
library(googleVis)
Gauge <-  gvisGauge(CityPopularity, 
options=list(min=0, 
max=800, greenFrom=500,                                     
greenTo=800, yellowFrom=300, yellowTo=500,
redFrom=0, 
redTo=300, width=400, height=300))
plot(Gauge)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQEpI.jpg)